# List of arrays in python numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np


A = np.empty((0, 3))

temp = np.array([1, 1, 1])

A = np.vstack([A, temp])
A = np.vstack([A, temp])

B = [A]

temp = np.array([2, 2, 0])

A = np.vstack([A, temp])
A = np.vstack([A, temp])
A = np.vstack([A, temp])
A = np.vstack([A, temp])

B = B.append(A)
```

So it does not work. How do I make a list of numpy arrays? The problem is that I have N types of points. Every type of points has M number of points. Every point is 3 coordinate array. Because I dont know in the first place the values of N and M, I need to do all the things dynamicly. When I had N = 1, vstack worked perfectly, but now every type has its own M, and array is not uniform anymore. So my guess - I need to work in numpy/vstack just as if I had N = 1, but afterwards just contain this np.empty((0, 3)) arrays somewhere. Is it possible? Maybe some empty object-type dictionary?

Thank you very mush in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work? Remember that `list.append` modifies the list in place and returns `None` - so when you do `B = B.append(A)` - you are assigning `B` to `None`

Comment: I ran it and it works.

Comment: Yep, I just replaced B = B.append(A) with B.append(A), and everything worked lol. Thanks

Comment: Can you close the topic, thanks !